# Vulnerabilities in .NET Core, ASP.NET Core Could Allow Elevation of Privilege

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

In reference to this [security advisory](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/security/4021279.aspx), I'm using Visual Studio Code and my csproj contains numerous affected packages.

Does .net core cli have an update or upgrade feature? I manually updated the packages using a text editor but that was a pain in the butt.

I tried downloading the latest nuget.exe [v4.1] to see if it could read the csproj but nope - it's expecting a packages.config which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

No the CLI was not affected, only the packages listed on the link you provided.

Comment: is there a command to automatically update the package versions listed in the csproj file?

Comment: No you have to do it manually. If you use visual studio you can easily update all the packages using the built-in nuget package manager. Doing it manually will be easier in the future as .NET Core 2.0 will come with a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.All` package.